# Bash - putting the first word of every line into an array

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing

I'm trying to put the first word from every sentence into an array.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name=$1
content=$(cat $file_name)
content=${content//"\n"/" "}
content=${content//". "/"\n"}
declare -A arr
cat $content| while read line;
do 
   line=($line)
   word=${line[0]}

if [[ ${arr[$word]} == '' ]] 
then
    arr[$word]=1
else
    let arr[$word]=${arr[$word]}+1
fi

done
```

Comment: Please provide example input and example of expected output

Comment: From every sentence or every line? And what actually separates a word from another. Am assuming a space, but just need to be clear on this.

Comment: Arguably, the first thing you are doing wrong is trying to use a shell (command interpreter) for general purpose text processing. The second thing is doing the array assignment on the RHS of a pipe - at least in bash, that will result in it being unavailable to the rest of the script (since it will run in a subshell).

Comment: @LuisAlvarado sounds _sentences_ because OP replacing all new lines with space, and then split into sentences by a dot-space, but yes title is saying different

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to do it in pure `bash` (for pedantic reasons?), use `cut` to produce the list of "first words", either in a `for wrd in $(cut "-d " -f1 $file_name ) ; do` loop, or if your word list is larger than `xargs --no-run-if-empty --show-limits </dev/null`, use `cut` and `xargs`.

In your existing code, you seem to be trying to slurp up all the data, and using only `bash` "`Parameter Expansion`", process it in `content` (a misuse of `bash` variables), then use it as a filename (`cat $content`), to flatten the data out and process 1 line at a time.

Of course, read `man cut`, `man xargs`, and `man bash`.

Comment: A pure bash solution might be required for a school assignment?

Comment: We don't do "school assignments" - they're left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: That's how I felt about it too when I first started on this site. But apparently many people are fine with it as long as the student displays they have already put effort into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an input file called `~/Documents/FirstWord.txt` containing:

```
Sample data file --> FirstWord.txt

This is a simple little input file used
as to test the bash script FirstWord.sh

There are three paragraphs separated by
one blank line. The output from this file
is "Sample", "This", "as", "one" and "is".
```

Create bash script called `~/Downloads/FirstWord.sh` containing:

```bash
!/bin/bash
file_name=$1
content=$(cat $file_name)
content="${content//"\n"/" "}"      # <-- You were missing double quotes around
content="${content//". "/"\n"}"     #     ${content//...} needed when spaces occur.
echo "$content" > /tmp/ContentFile  # Create temporary file of massaged data.

declare arr         # Define regular array.

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
#      ^ 1.       ^ 2.          ^ 3.

# 1. IFS='' (or IFS=) prevents leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed.
# 2. -r prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.
# 3. || [[ -n $line ]] prevents the last line from being ignored if it doesn't end with a \n (since read returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters EOF).

# ** Above explanation from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/6929343

    first=${line%% *}   # Extract first word from line.
    arr+=($first)       # Assign $first to next available array entry.

done < /tmp/ContentFile # <-- In bash it is best to read files at end of while loop.

echo ${arr[@]}          # Dump array contents to screen.
rm -f /tmp/ContentFile  # Remove temporary file.

# +============================================================================+
# | Original program with comments below                                       |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# declare -A arr                        <-- We don't need associative array.

# cat $content| while read line;        <-- Unconventional method
# do                                    <-- I usually append to line above.
    # line=($line) <--- Assigning a variable to itself has no effect.
    # word=${line[0]} < Not sure what would be accomplished by this.

    # if [[ ${arr[$word]} == '' ]]      <-- I've indented for readability.
    # then
    #     arr[$word]=1                  <-- "word" isn't a counter, won't work.
    # else
    #     let arr[$word]=${arr[$word]}+1<-- Once again "word" isn't a counter.
    # fi
# done                                  <-- Where input to while loop shoud be.
```

Save the two files and then in the terminal type:

```
~$ cd Downloads
~/Downloads$ chmod a+x FirstWord.sh
~/Downloads$ ./FirstWord.sh FirstWord.txt
Sample This as There one is
```